# Python IRC and LinkNet port troubles

Tags: python, sockets, bots, port, irc

I am trying to make a python IRC bot that connects to LinkNet (I'm connecting to the address `irc.de2.link-net.org`). Usually LinkNet tells you to join with port +7000.

Here's some of my code:

```
self.irc.connect((server, 6667))
```

Since the port has to be a number, I can't pass `"+7000"` or else it will throw a `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

And if I put `+7000` on its own like so:

```
self.irc.connect((server, +7000))
```

I get a connection error:

```
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a different server.

I figured that out before anyone actually responded to my question so it's not really an answer but it helped me move on with my project, so there.

Answer (score 0):

**LinkNet used SSL only 7000** not  6667. You must used **import ssl**.

```
1=irc.link-net.nl:7000
2=linknet.sh.cvut.cz:7000
3=irc.link-net.fi:7000
4=rc.link-net.no:7000
5=irc.link-net.be:7000
6=irc.ca2.link-net.org:7000
7=irc.se.link-net.org:7000
8=irc.us-ca2.link-net.org:7000
9=irc.de2.link-net.org:7000
```